# Looking for information about a triangle center style construction

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, triangles

A student of mine asked me about an odd triangle center construction I'd not seen before; I wasn't able to figure out much about it or identify it amongst the [many existing ones](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/etc.html), so with his permission I thought I'd ask about it here.

*(Actually, he requested that I ask this here quite some time ago and I kept forgetting. Mea culpa!)*

The construction is the following. Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with circumcenter $O$, let $\mathscr{A,B,C}$ be the circles with center $A,B,C$ and radius $\overline{AO},\overline{BO},\overline{CO}$ respectively. Let $a,b,c$ be the extended edges opposite $A,B,C$ respectively.

Now we construct some new points. Let $A'$ be the midpoint of the segment connecting the closest-to-$A$ point of intersection between $\mathscr{B}$ and $c$ and the closest-to-$A$ point of intersection between $\mathscr{C}$ and $b$; define $B'$ and $C'$ similarly.

The point $Z_{ABC}$ my student is interested in is the intersection of the lines $\overleftrightarrow{AA'}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BB'}$, and $\overleftrightarrow{CC'}$ *(in the picture below, $A'=L$, $B'=K$, $C'=M$, and $Z_{ABC}=N$)*. This common point of intersection does not always exist, but does for a large number of triangles; my student was originally interested in a characterization of *when* this point exists (this was a challenge problem he created for himself), but now is generally interested in what can be said about $Z_{ABC}$ at all.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer ...

---

This is $X(3302)$ in [Kimberling's Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart3.html#X3302). More-accurately, your student's point agrees with $X(3302)$ *when the former exists*; the latter *always* exists, because it replaces the notion of "closest intersection" (eg, $F$) of point and side-line with something less fragile, namely
$$F:=B+\frac{r}{c}(A−B)$$
(That is, $F$ is the point at circumradius-distance from $B$ in the direction of $A$.) Incidentally, using the "other" intersections of the circles and lines via $$F:=B−\frac{r}{c}(A−B)$$
(note the sign change) yields [$X(3300)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart3.html#X3300).

ETC describes $X(3302)$ and $X(3300)$ merely as the isogonal conjugates of $X(3301)$ and $X(3299)$, respectively. In turn, $X(3301)$ is defined as the intersection of lines joining $X(35)X(371)$ and $X(36)X(372)$, while $X(3299)$ joins the same points in a different way: $X(35)X(372)$ and $X(36)X(371)$. Following that trail further is left as an exercise to the reader, but I'd be curious to know if there's a deeper connection between the referenced points and your student's construction(s). (New challenge problem, perhaps?)

In any case, your student should write to Kimberling (see "Contact the Keeper" on the ETC's [Links](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/links.html) page) describing those construction(s).

Comment: Awesome as always, thanks!

Comment: Belatedly: how did you figure out that this was $X(3302)$? (I presume you're not simply familiar with the first few thousand triangle centers, but one never knows. :P)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: The ETC Tables page has an item for doing a [lookup using the construction on a $6$-$9$-$13$ triangle](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/Search_6_9_13.html). The introduction gives a recipe for turning trilinear/barycentric coordinates into a single reference number, for which you do a text search. (Like everything else in the ETC, the user experience could stand some improvement. (Clark K, if you're reading: Please drop me a line. I'd love to work on this.)) The recipe is a bit convoluted, but converting it to a Mathematica function is relatively straightforward.